# Как верстать, через css таблицы или html?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с таблицей, я могу использовать html разметку таблиц и css через 'display: table;'. Однако, как определиться где и когда нужно использовать одно, а когда другое.

Comment: Да можно и без всяких `display: table;` обходиться.. Тут всё от вашей фантазии зависит

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто.

Когда вам нужно жестко-прежестко структурировать данные, гридами и флексами не получается, а браузер выдает мешанину - делаете старую добрую таблицу, десять минут - и все отлично. Потом, конечно, когда заказчик захочет модный адаптивный дизайн, будут трудности.

Когда у вас все в жизни хорошо, адаптивный дизайн вам роднее собственного папы, а табличное представление нужно по какой-то дикой причине, реализуете через CSS.